# chromedriver cannot be found in heroku after installed

Tags: google-chrome, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

How do you find chrome driver in Heroku?

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver.git -a app-name

 ›   Error: The buildpack
 ›   https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver.git is
 ›   already set on your app.
```

Chromedriver cannot be found in heroku app.

```
heroku run bash -a app-name
which chromedriver
```

Google driver cannot be found by searching file name as well.

```
$ find . -name *driver
./client/node_modules/node-sass/src/libsass/script/tap-driver
./client/node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/transport/driver
./client/node_modules/websocket-driver
./client/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver
./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/capybara-3.16.1/lib/capybara/driver
./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.0.1/ext/libsass/script/tap-driver
./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver
./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.0/lib/websocket/driver
./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.0/ext/websocket-driver
```